# Getting a Forbidden

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, devops, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-10

I've got a vps and at the moment I'm trying to access my newly created laravel app. It's just the original laravel installation, I haven't made any changes. But when I go to the url I get

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource Apache/2.1.1 (Ubuntu) Server at testing-laravel.mydomain.com Port 80

What I've done so far is

1. in the root directory I created a folder called testing-laravel.mydomain.com and I installed laravel in there
2. then I went to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and created `laravel-testing-site.conf`
3. then I added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName testing-laravel.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /root/testing-laravel/public

    <Directory /root/testing-laravel/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

4. then I ran `sudo a2ensite laravel-testing-site.conf`
5. then i ran `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`
6. then i ran `sudo service apache2 restart`

I've also gone to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and this is what I have in the last line

> [core:error] [pid 3820] (13)Permission denied: [client ipaddress:51284] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/root/testing-laravel) because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: Apache uses the user `www-data` to read files and access directories. Presumably your `/root` folder files belong to root so apache won't be able to access them

Comment: @apokryfos - as far as I know `www-data` should have access, because for `/root/testing-laravel/` it has `drwxr-wr-x 13 www-data www-data` in the terminal when i do `ls -la`

Answer (score 0):

1. Chmod your root folder by:

   sudo chmod -R 755 /root/testing-laravel
2. Give www-data user an ownership to it by:

   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /root/testing-laravel
3. Check if SE Linux is enabled. If it is, check, if it blocks your app by:

   ls -Z /root/testing-laravel
4. At the end I'd recommend you to read logs and continue your investigation by:

   tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log

If you found your problem through logs, do not forget to put the answer here

Comment: I tried what you suggested and all I got in my logs was `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 510 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"` and
`"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 509 "http://testing-laravel.mydomain.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Right there you should have error.log too, check your VH conf: 

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log